# Moving Wordpress with Headway to a new domain breaks the site

Tags: wordpress

I have a client's wordpress site that is built using Wordpress and Headway.  I need to move it to a new domain on a new shared server ( same host provider with the same hardware configuration ).

I've moved many wordpress setups like this before, including Wordpress / Headway combos.  I've also, during debug, used Headway's documentation and videos to double check that I'm doing everything correctly.

I moved the database over and replaced all occurrences of the old domain with the new domain, and updated all filepaths.  Then I copied the `public_html` folder to the new server.  The site should be working at this point.

Instead I get the Headway error message `No Content to Display` on an otherwise empty html page.  I've traced the problem to the `wp-config` table where Headway stores serialized data for it's blocks.  I can update data throughout the database to the new domain everywhere except in these Headway entries in the `wp-config` table.  As soon as I update those, the site starts to fall apart all over the place, and if I update them all, the site loads the Headway error message `No Content to Display`.  The underlying Wordpress system seems to still be working as I can load the `/wp-admin` console and all my content exists and looks correct.

If I trace the problem deeper, it appears that the Wordpress function `get_options()` is failing in the Headway file `data-layout-options.php`.  I have been unable to debug any further.

The site works perfectly on the original domain, and, in theory, I'm doing a direct copy of all data and then simply replacing the old domain with the new domain.

Can anyone help with a similar problem?  It feels like I'm chasing a bug in the code when really it's some sort of simple oversight or config setting that has been munged.  Please help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was indeed close to the problem.

The serialized Headway data in the Wordpress `wp-config` table contains string lengths.  Migrating the database oneself, and then grepping and replacing the old domain with the new domain and old web folder file path with the new web folder file path causes unserialization to fail in the Wordpress system ( eg. the get_options() Wordpress function ).

Instead of writing a custom script to deal with the string lengths, I tested a few database migration plugins.  [WP Migrate DB](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-migrate-db/) was the winner and solved the problem.

**Migrating the Database**

Install the plugin on the original domain ( original Wordpress install ).  It will ask you to input the new domain and the new file path of your web directory ( the web directory file path is very important as well ).  In my case, for example, the file path of the web directory had changed from /home2/old_username to /home6/new_username.

The plugin will then dump the entire Wordpress Database and replace all occurances of the old domain and old file path with the new domain and file path of the web directory.  The .sql dump will then save locally on your computer.

This was not perfect however, and I still needed to do a few of my own grep and replaces.  Additionally, I had to be careful about this because a few of the ones that were missed were in the Headway serialized data and I had to do MySQL queries to make sure I updated the string length properly.

These few updates were missed because some of the database entries had `http://www.olddomain.com` and some had `http://olddomain.com`.  The plugin did not catch it all, but made it manageable to replace by hand.

Finally, I had to import this updated .sql dump into an empty Wordpress database on the new domain.

**Moral of the story is that Headway V3 is not simple to migrate to a new domain.**  You must be very meticulous.

Another option, that I did not try because it costs >$75 was [BackupBuddy](http://pluginbuddy.com/purchase/backupbuddy/).  It's likely that BackupBuddy will still miss some domain and file path updates, so be careful.

Comment: I've had the same problem several times. I've been using searchreplacedb2 from interconnectit (http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) it's should unserialize-reserialize everything, but for some reason HeadWay still breaks when moved to a new domain this way.

Comment: @mikkelbreum - Did you ever get this application to work and maintain serialized headway data?

Comment: Not without doing some additional grep/replace: "This was not perfect however, and I still needed to do a few of my own grep and replaces. Additionally, I had to be careful about this because a few of the ones that were missed were in the Headway serialized data and I had to do MySQL queries to make sure I updated the string length properly."

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution of T. Brian Jones and have just applied it for WordPress 3.8.1 with HEADWAY 3.6.2.

All works fine. 
One trick for newbes like me: if you don't know the file path on the server where you are moving your database, before you do database dump install WP Migrate DB on this server, run the plugin (Tools) and get the path from there...

Thank's TBJ

Maciej